# mostrar o arquivo como imagem

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou desenvolvendo um site com node js, ele tem funcionalidade de upload/download dos arquivos como (pdf, slide, docx, etc.). E capaz de mostrar os arquivos que foram uploads. Agora tenho uma problema de mostrar ele no view (queria que ele mostra a imagem da 1a pagina do arquivo no view) exemplo como no site slideshare.
Alguem poderia dar um cami[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]nho? Ja tentei pesquisar mas nao encontrei.
Obrigado.